# Sql select query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a table and it's structured the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  + Some additional fields
  KEY `type` (`type`)
)
```

What's the most efficient way to write the following query: `Select the item with the maximal value of some certain type, let's say 'type0'.`

---

If it's possible, could you also explain, what happens beneath the query *(I mean, something that can affect the resulting algorithmic complexity)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM 'table'
WHERE type = 'type0'
ORDER BY 'value' DESCENDING
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'table'
WHERE type = 'type0'
ORDER BY 'value' DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I guess. The most important part is that you have index on both 'type' and 'value'

Thanks @Andrew for pointing he is asking for MySQL. Cheers.

Comment: It's tagged mysql, so use LIMIT 1 at the end not TOP 1

Comment: Adding indexes is optional. It will decrease performance of inserts, updates and deletes so is something that has to be evaluated based on how many rows you expect, how frequently you will run this query, and how frequently the table is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Finding just one row (with maximal value):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableX 
WHERE type = 'type0'
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Finding all rows with same (maximal) value:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableX 
WHERE type = 'type0'
  AND value =
      ( SELECT MAX(value)
        FROM tableX
        WHERE type = 'type0'
      )
```

And index on `(type, value)` (for InnoDB table) or on `(type, value, PK)` (for MyISAM table) will be useful.